# INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE .. WHERE foreign_key_id = foreign_key_id

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having this (pseudo) code inside a function

```
if(!$foo->id){

    $foo = INSERT INTO foos (....) VALUES (.....)
    $foo->id = new_inserted_id();


    INSERT INTO my_table (foo_id, field1, field2, field3) 
    VALUES ($foo->id, 'aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc');

} else {
    // UPDATE $foo and existing record in my_table
    $foo = UPDATE foos SET ..... WHERE id = $foo->id;

    // first check if already exist record having foo-id - this is basically for old records
    $q = SELECT COUNT(id) AS count 
         FROM my_table
         WHERE foo_id = $foo->id
         LIMIT1

    if($q->count > 0){

       // update
       UPDATE my_table SET field1 = 'aaaa', field2 = 'bbbb', field3 = 'cccc'
       WHERE foo_id = $foo->id
       LIMIT 1;

    } else {

       INSERT INTO my_table (foo_id, field1, field2, field3) 
       VALUES ($foo->id, 'aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc');

    }

}
```

I want to focus in the `UPDATE` section (the first else). Instead of this select and the check whether is a new insert or update, can I do a `INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` but also having a `WHERE` statement in there? Something like this:

```
INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE ... WHERE WHERE foo_id = $foo->id
```

Comment: You can't add a WHERE clause to an INSERT statement, but if you set `fee_id` to be unique, then the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` should trigger

Comment: What do you mean? Not entirely sure I understand

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` triggers when it hits a field marked as unique, and the value already exists. I'd suggest reading up on the MYSQL column types and the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a normal where clause when using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, mysql does not allow it. You can use conditional statements as a workaround.

Something like this may be what you are looking for.

```
$q = "INSERT INTO my_table (foo_id, field1, field2, field3)
($foo->id, 'aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET
field1 = IF( foo_id = VALUES(foo_id), VALUES('aaaaa'), 'bbbb' ),
field2 = VALUES('bbbbb'),
field3 = VALUES('cccc')";
```

Comment: `$foo->id` makes no sense to SQL.